# TypeScript passing Variables

Tags: typescript

I'm brand new to typescript - having an issue with variables and scope.

I have 2 public methods, one requires a string.
The first method calls the second, from within a jQuery click function (which means I can't use this.methodName anymore). I tried fixing the scope in a logical method but TS complains that:

Supplied Paramaters do not match any signature of call target.
Could not select overload for 'call' expression.

```
    public test1() {
        //fix scope
        var scopeFix = () => this.test2;

        $("#test").click(function () {
            //this.test2("blah");
            //^^^ This doesn't work because "this." is used by jquery
            scopeFix("blah");
        });
    }

    public test2(testString:string) {
        alert(testString);
    }
```

I'm sure it's something silly (like me mixing JS and TS too much) - any ideas?

Comment: Use a local to store a reference to the `this` scope you need, http://jsfiddle.net/9DjGp/

Comment: So close! 

Thanks mate.

Comment: Sure, it's a common question. Nothing to do with typescript though. The typescript error is because the `scopeFix` function is a paramterless function that returns a function, so your call site is wrong, it should be more like `fixScope()('blah');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript you can do this:

```
public test1() {
    $("#test").click(() => {
        this.test2("blah");
    });
}
```

Note the `() => {}` syntax. To give you an idea of what this is doing, check out the compiled JavaScript:

```
YourClass.prototype.test1 = function () {
    var _this = this;

    $("#test").click(function () {
        _this.test2("blah");
    });
};
```